# How do I check if a channel already exists?

Tags: python, sqlite, discord, discord.py

I have a ticket system and with this also tickets can be created on reaction. However, you can press the reaction as many times as you want and new channels keep coming. How can I prevent this?

**My code:**

```py
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_raw_reaction_add(self, payload):
        user = self.bot.get_user(payload.user_id)
        guild = self.bot.get_guild(payload.guild_id)
        if payload.user_id == self.bot.user.id or user.bot:
            return
        cursor = reaction_conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ticket_messages ("message_id" INT, "reaction" TEXT)')
        cursor.execute('SELECT reaction FROM ticket_messages WHERE message_id = ?', (payload.message_id,))
        row = cursor.fetchone()
        cursor.close()
        reaction_conn.commit()
        if row is not None and row[0] == str(payload.emoji):
            await self.createTicket(guild, user, None, f "Created via reaction.")
            channel = self.bot.get_channel(payload.channel_id)
            message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)
            await message.remove_reaction(payload.emoji, guild.get_member(payload.user_id))
```

I tried going via an `if channel` argument, but that doesn`t work.

**EDIT after comment:**

```py
    def enable_reactions(self, message_id: int, reaction: str, reactor_id: int):
        cursor = reaction_conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ticket_messages ("message_id" INT, "reaction" TEXT, "reactor_id" INT)')
        cursor.execute('INSERT INTO ticket_messages(message_id, reaction, reactor_id) VALUES (?, ?, ? )',
                       (message_id, reaction, reactor_id))
        cursor.close()
        reaction_conn.commit()
        log.debug(f'Ticket per reaction created for message ID {message_id}')
```

And also the new `listener`:

```py
    @commands.Cog.listener()
        #Other stuff
        cursor = reaction_conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ticket_messages ("message_id" INT, "reaction" TEXT, "reactor_id" INT)')
        cursor.execute('SELECT reaction FROM ticket_messages WHERE reactor_id = ?', (payload.user_id,))
        row = cursor.fetchone()
        cursor.close()
        reaction_conn.commit()
        if row is not None and row[0] == str(payload.emoji):
            await self.createTicket(guild, user, None, f"Created via reaction.")# update this to add user_data
            channel = self.bot.get_channel(payload.channel_id)
            message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)
            await message.remove_reaction(payload.emoji, guild.get_member(payload.user_id))
        else:
            channel3 = self.bot.get_channel(812711563261247518)
            await channel3.send("You already have a ticket.") # ctx.send will not work
```

I still get an `qlite3.OperationalError: no such column: reactor_id` error but I assume maybe it has something to do with the following:

```py
    @server_ticket.command(name='reaction', aliases=["setup", "reactions"])
    @commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
    async def server_ticket_reaction(self, ctx):
        """Allows a server mod to setup a message to enable ticket creation per reaction"""
        timeout_embed = discord.Embed(
            description="Oops! You took to long, the setup process has been canceled. Try again!", color=self.bot.color)

        def channel_check(msg):
            return discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.text_channels,
                                     mention=msg.content) is not None and msg.author.id == ctx.author.id and msg.channel.id == ctx.channel.id

        def emoji_check(reaction, user):
            return reaction.message.id == emoji_msg.id and user == ctx.message.author and reaction.message.channel.id == ctx.channel.id

        def message_check(msg):
            return len(msg.content) < 2048 and msg.author.id == ctx.author.id and msg.channel.id == ctx.channel.id

        def title_check(msg):
            return len(msg.content) < 256 and msg.author.id == ctx.author.id and msg.channel.id == ctx.channel.id

        channel_embed = discord.Embed(
            description="Mention the **channel** where you want to have the ticket creation message.",
            color=self.bot.color)
        channel_embed.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
        await ctx.send(embed=channel_embed)
        try:
            channel_mention = await self.bot.wait_for('message', timeout=45.0, check=channel_check)
            channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.text_channels, mention=channel_mention.content)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            return await ctx.send(embed=timeout_embed)
        emoji_embed = discord.Embed(
            description="Now **react** with the emoji you want to use for ticket creation to **this** "
                        "message.\n:warning: Please use an emoji from this server or an Unicode emoji.",
            color=self.bot.color)
        emoji_embed.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
        emoji_msg = await ctx.send(embed=emoji_embed)
        try:
            reaction = await self.bot.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=45.0, check=emoji_check)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            return await ctx.send(embed=timeout_embed)
        message_embed = discord.Embed(title="Title", description="Content", color=self.bot.color)
        message_embed.set_footer(text=self.bot.user.name, icon_url=self.bot.user.avatar_url)
        await ctx.send(
            "What should the message contain?\n\nThe format is:\n**Message\nTitle\nContent**\n\n*This will be the "
            "**Message** before the embed.*",
            embed=message_embed)
        try:
            message = await self.bot.wait_for('message', timeout=120.0, check=message_check)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            return await ctx.send(embed=timeout_embed)
        try:
            title = await self.bot.wait_for('message', timeout=120.0, check=title_check)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            return await ctx.send(embed=timeout_embed)
        try:
            content = await self.bot.wait_for('message', timeout=120.0, check=message_check)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            return await ctx.send(embed=timeout_embed)
        try:
            reaction_embed = discord.Embed(title=title.content, description=content.content, color=self.bot.color)
            # reaction_embed.set_footer(text=self.bot.user.name, icon_url=self.bot.user.avatar_url)
            reaction_embed.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
            reaction_embed.set_footer(text="To create a ticket, react to the icon", icon_url=self.bot.user.avatar_url)
            ticket_msg = await channel.send(message.content, embed=reaction_embed)
            await ticket_msg.add_reaction(reaction[0].emoji)
            self.enable_reactions(ticket_msg.id, str(reaction[0].emoji))
```

It says at the last `)` that Parameter `reactor_id` is unfilled.

Comment: By response, do you mean reacting again? What do you want the bot to do when they react(respond) again?

Comment: I mean reacting again, yes. If the user reacts again but still has a ticket open I want the bot to say something like "You have an open ticket" and do not create another one. Do you want to see more code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify your table to include user data

```py
@commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_raw_reaction_add(self, payload):
        # other stuff
        cursor = reaction_conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ticket_messages ("message_id" INT, "reaction" TEXT, "reactor_id" INT)')
        cursor.execute('SELECT reaction FROM ticket_messages WHERE reactor_id = ?', (payload.user_id,))
        row = cursor.fetchone()
        # other stuff
        if row is not None and row[0] == str(payload.emoji):
            await self.createTicket(guild, user, None, f "Created via reaction.")# update this to add user_data
        else:
            await ctx.send(f"You have an open ticket")
```

We are using user_id to restrict one active ticker per user, if you want a user to create more tickets after the current ticket has been closed, you have to delete the row or set it to a default value (0) if you want to use it again.

Comment: I get an `OperationalError` message with `no such column: reactor_id`. I edited my code and expanded so you can maybe see what I did wrong.

Comment: ` cursor.execute('INSERT INTO ticket_messages(message_id, reaction, reactor_id) VALUES (?, ?, ? )', (message_id, reaction, reactor_id)) 
` you haven't added reactor_id to new row

Comment: Hm, I am doing something wrong. After inserting your answer to `enable_reactions` I still get the same message

Comment: Have you deleted your old table? Because the old table doesn't have the column `reactor_id` and it looks like that is the source of the problem.

Comment: Looks like that was the problem. I deleted my database and now it partly works. It does not create a channel but gives me the error message that a ticket already exists. Is your example set up like that a user can create more channel after his own got closed? (Error message appears even if there is no ticket.)

Comment: In addition in my line `self.enable_reactions(ticket_msg.id, str(reaction[0].emoji))` it says that `reactor_id` is unfilled, guess there is a problem too.

Comment: Looks like this is going on to become an entirely new question, might want to ask it separately.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see any reactor_id in the docs.
There is user_id maybe you could try replacing that.
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_raw_reaction#discord.RawReactionActionEvent

Comment: reactor_id is being used as a column in the table, its the same as user_id, just a different name for our reference.